# AMD FX-9590 - Max memory speed

Tags: memory, overclocking

First let me tell you my system config.

```
CPU: AMD FX-9590
Ram: Kingston 2x8GB 2400MHz
SSD: kingston 120 GB
HDD: 1 TB
PSU: 750 Watt corsair
GPU: 2Gb NVIDIA GeForce GT 630
Motherboard: Asus crosshair V formula-z
```

My motherboard seems to support up to 2400MHz ram, however my CPU seems to support 1866MHz.
Its strange, since I have not found any other am3+ cpus, which support 2400MHz ram.

Whenever I turn 2400MHz ram on in the bios, I get randomly BSOD (BlueScreenOfDeath). Is there any way I can get the benefits from my 2400MHz ram?

Also will I need to make the ram voltage higher? If yes, how high?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to down clock your RAM. 
when the CPU does not support 2400 MHz - turn it to 1866 MHz it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same setup and it works just fine.
Not same memory but same speed. Use docp and make sure to set the  right timings and voltage.
For my corsair vengence cl 11 its 11-13-13-31 @ 1.65v and tRC at 44.
I know its an old question but this is for people who has trouble with this in the future.

Comment: It's great that this works for you, but the question was written because it didn't work for the questioner.  If someone else has the same problem as the questioner, how would this answer help them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the memory controller of this CPU only supports up to 1866 MHz RAM. It may go slighly higher, but it is not reliable. I have also 2400 MHz RAM chips (4 X 8). At DCOP per XPS (2400 MHz) it does not boot at all. At 2133 it boots but my Win 10 gets stuck.
I have run my system very stable at 1866 MHz and without any problem. The motherboard automatically sets the DRAM voltage to 1.63 V, while at 2400 MHz it is 1.65V.